# Microsoft Teams Adaptive Card Input.ChoiceSet Default Across Platforms

Tags: microsoft-teams

Rendering the same Microsoft Teams Adaptive Card Input.ChoiceSet without a "value" (i.e. no default), shows a default in Microsoft Teams Android Client, but no default choice in the drop-down for OS X, web or iOS Teams clients...

How do I render the same input.choiceSet in an adaptive card with no default for the same card across all clients?

[Teams Android and OS X Render Same Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIbbk.jpg)

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
      "content": {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.0",
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
              {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Command Center",
                "size": "large",
                "weight": "bolder"
              },
              {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Please choose a scenario to submit."
              },
              {
                "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                "id": "scenario-id",
                "style": "compact",
                "isMultiSelect": false,
                "choices": [
                  {
                    "value": "71ae62b1-f04e-11e9-b862-577308a243ca",
                    "title": "Foo's Bar"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "16db3124-f42d-11e9-bde7-819811d8b810",
                    "title": "Second"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "actions": [
          {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "id": "popup",
            "title": "Continue...",
            "data": {
              "msteams": {
                "type": "task/fetch"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@MarkSingleWire Thanks for reporting this to us. Adaptive card should not be picking any default value for the dropdown. We have raised a bug for this and we are looking into it.